# Ionic side menu navigation setRoot refresh page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a problem with navigation in ionic side menu. I need to preserve the state of the pages when the user navigate with this menu. But when the user click in one option of the menu `setRoot` refresh the page.
I'm using the ionic starter template named side menu (https://github.com/ionic-team/starters/tree/master/ionic-angular/official/sidemenu).
I make the following changes:

-In home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h3>Ionic Menu Starter</h3>

  <p>
    {{text}} <button primary (click)="change();" >Change text</button>
  </p>

  <button ion-button secondary menuToggle>Toggle Menu</button>
</ion-content>
```

I have added a text and a button which change the text.

-In home.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  text:string;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.text="Initial text";
  }
  change(){
     this.text="Text changed!";
  }
}
```

So when I click in the button, the text change, but when I navigate to the list, and return to the home, the text show "Initial text", but I need ti poreserve the state and show "Text changed!".
I know that it's because the call `setRoot` method in app.component.ts, but I can't call `push` method because it open a new page, and when I navigate the stack increase... I need some solition that works like tabs navigation.